# SFTP to REST using Camel

Tags: rest, apache-camel

I am very new to camel. I want to pull some xml file from a sftp location and feed the content to existing REST endpoint. Below is my configuration,

```
<route id="xml.FOEBRE">
    <from uri="<sftp server uri>"/>
    <marshal>
        <string/>
    </marshal>
    <setHeader headerName="Content-Type">
        <constant>application/xml</constant>
    </setHeader>
    <doTry>
        <to uri="<REST URI>?httpMethod=POST"/>
        <bean ref="myListener" method="onPushSuccess"/>
        <doCatch>
            <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
            <!--<log message="error : ${exception.message}" loggingLevel="ERROR"/>-->
            <process ref="globalExceptionListener"/>
        </doCatch>
    </doTry>    
</route>
```

I am able to call it, but I want to capture the response status and body of the REST call. In my success processor I have written,

```
Message message = exchange.getIn();
int status = message.getHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, Integer.class);
LOG.debug("Response status : {}", status);

LOG.debug("Payload successfully sent to securecargo");
String body = message.getBody(String.class);
LOG.debug("Response Body : {}", body);
```

This code is returning me the proper response body. But the same code (in catch listener) is not working when the status code is 400. I have two question,

- How to catch this response body when status code is 400? My processor in catch block is never invoked.
- Why I getting this body in exchange.getIn(), not in exchange.getOut()?

Note: My REST service returns two status, 201 for success and 400 for failure. I know my service returns a JSON payload both in success and failre scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer

- My processor was getting invoked, but encounters a NPE while excuting the processor body and that exception was internally consumed by camel
- During an exception, all exception related information can be retrieved from exception object itself rather than In/Out

Below is my exception handler (processor) code,

```
HttpOperationFailedException cause = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, HttpOperationFailedException.class);
LOG.error(cause.getMessage());
final String responseBody = cause.getResponseBody();
LOG.error(responseBody);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll get the response code from headers inside `getIn()` method instead. By facing any issue (I mean, HTTP-call errors) other than the expected response, an exception will be thrown and set into the exchange properties (Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but how to get the response body. exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class) returns me the request body.

Comment: I would suggest to check if your method actually changes the request body

Comment: Does the endpoint you're invoking really change the content? Probably it doesn't. Try checking its behavior via postman, for instance.

Comment: Yes, my response body is different in when the REST status code is 201 or 400. Now I can capture the body by exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class) in case of success [Please refer to the updated question]. But not in case of error. Also why I am getting response in In message, not in Out message.